# Jquery Select2 multiselect with Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: jquery-select2, naturallyspeaking

I have implemented a select2 multiselect for list of states in a application, and it works fine using typing the state names. But with Dragon NaturallySpeaking software if you speak in select2 to select a state, it only show the last char of what you spoke and do not autosearch, you have to press space to see the whole text and then press backspace to start the search, looks like some event does not fire when you speak than type. Not sure if there is any solution that I can try. I have tried to fire the change event manually.. but not working !

Answer (score 0):

Since the select2 box is not Select and Say, you probably need to dictate into the dictation box and transfer it over.  Or, write a script to take in the dictation, convert it to what you need, and then paste it to clipboard.  Then go over to box and paste from clipboard.  Let us know what worked . . .

Answer (score 0):

I have added a check if the selected element class is select2-search__field then I trigger a $(activeElement).trigger('change') in that element. that seems doing the job